# Orientation of UIImage on UITableViewCell and Coredata changed after saved

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, core-data

I have the following code on the Table detail view of the table which allows user to take picture or load image from library to the UIImageView. Then this will be saved using core data. 
After saving, it will go back to the UITable. Strangely, the image on the UITable after saving is also changed from portrait orientation to horizontal. May I know if my code has anything wrong.

Many Thanks

DetailView.m

```
- (IBAction)editSaveButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    // If we are adding a new picture (because we didnt pass one from the table) then create an entry
    if (!currentPicture)
        self.currentPicture = (Pictures *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Pictures" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];


if (imageField.image)
    {
        // Resize and save a smaller version for the table
        float resize = 74.0;
        float actualWidth = imageField.image.size.width;
        float actualHeight = imageField.image.size.height;
        float divBy, newWidth, newHeight;
        if (actualWidth > actualHeight) {
            divBy = (actualWidth / resize);
            newWidth = resize;
            newHeight = (actualHeight / divBy);
        } else {
            divBy = (actualHeight / resize);
            newWidth = (actualWidth / divBy);
            newHeight = resize;
        }
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, newWidth, newHeight);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
        [imageField.image drawInRect:rect];
        UIImage *smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        // Save the small image version
        NSData *smallImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageField.image);
        [self.currentPicture setSmallPicture:smallImageData];
    }

    //  Commit item to core data
    NSError *error;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error])
        NSLog(@"Failed to add new picture with error: %@", [error domain]);

    //  Automatically pop to previous view now we're done adding
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)imageFromAlbum:(id)sender
{    takePhotoBtn.hidden=YES;
    choosePhotoBtn.hidden=YES;
    takephoto.hidden=NO;
    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

//  Take an image with camera
- (IBAction)imageFromCamera:(id)sender
{    takePhotoBtn.hidden=YES;
    choosePhotoBtn.hidden=YES;
    takephoto.hidden=NO;
    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

TableView.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Get the core data object we need to use to populate this table cell
    Pictures *currentCell = [pictureListData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //  Fill in the cell contents
    cell.textLabel.text = [currentCell title];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [currentCell desc];
    cell.backgroundColor =  [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lightblue.jpg"]];
    //  If a picture exists then use it
    if ([currentCell smallPicture])
    {
        cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[currentCell smallPicture]];
    }
    tableView.opaque = NO;
    [tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gray.jpg"]]];

    return cell;
```

Comment: It only happen in real iPhone. In simulator everything is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change following part..

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, newWidth, newHeight);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];//here you can use your image view instead of self,view...
[imageField.image drawInRect:rect];
UIImage *smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Hope, this will help you..

Answer (score 2):

your image resizing does not take the image rotation into account. The simplest solution that i know: Assign the image to an UIImageView with the desired size and use.

```
[imgView.layer renderInContext:context];
```

this takes all possible orientations into account.